# How to add secure env variables to Remix.run project?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Following the documentation the best way to add env variables is to add them on your server but how to processed **secret** url that should be in root component (e.g. Google Api )?

Pass them through loader don't resolve this problem because of security. Any user will be able to see variables in network tab
[Env variable in network tab][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VizIt.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any API key that needs to stay secret needs to be used on the server *only* and not returned in a loader response.

That being said, for Google Maps client-side functionality, you have no choice but to expose your API key to the client. You should instead secure it using Google's recommended practice of [Restricting your API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to specific domains and APIs.